# ¿Por qué cuando hago una llamada kill a procesos hermanos o abuelos estos no reciben nada?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un programa en c, en el que creo un arbol de procesos como este:

[image: Arbol de procesos]

Desde el proceso Z llamo a los procesos A, B, X o Y en función del segundo parámetro recibido.
En el código, cuando he ido llamando a fork(), me he ido guardando los pid de los hijos, de forma que en Z podemos acceder al pid de X e Y con esas variables (Para A y B uso las funciones getppid). He comprobado que en Z los pid son correctos, pero aun así, no se activan cuando llamo a la función Kill, excepto el proceso B, que si que funciona.

Aquí un fragmento del código:

```c
pidY = fork();
if (pidY == 0)
{
    //Proceso Y
    printf("Soy el proceso Y: mi pid es %d. Mi padre es %d. Mi abuelo es %d. Mi bisabuelo es %d\n", getpid(), pidB, pidA, pidArb);
    int estadoY;
    signal(SIGUSR1, casoXY);
    wait(&estadoY);
}
else
{
    pidZ = fork();
    if (pidZ == 0)
    {
        //Proceso Z
        printf("Soy el proceso Z: mi pid es %d. Mi padre es %d. Mi abuelo es %d. Mi                 bisabuelo es %d\n", getpid(), pidB, pidA, pidArb);
        sleep(atoi(argv[2]));

        switch (argv[1][0])
        {
            case 'A':
                //pstree
                printf("Acabo y eligo a A\n");
                kill(pidA, SIGUSR1);
                break;

            case 'B':
                //pstree
                printf("Acabo y eligo a B\n");
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
                break;

            case 'X':
                //ls
                printf("Acabo y eligo a X\n");
                printf("Proceso X: %d\n", pidX);
                kill(pidX, SIGUSR1);
                break;

            case 'Y':
                //ls
                printf("Acabo y eligo a Y\n");
                printf("Proceso Y: %d\n", pidY);
                kill(pidY, SIGUSR1); //TODO
                break;
        }
        int estadoZ;
        wait(&estadoZ);
    }
}
```

Por si afectara en algo, estoy compilando en Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

debes crear un manejador para que cuando le llegue una señal al proceso padre este mate a sus procesos hijos. Ejemplo:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (signal (SIGUSR1 , manejadorSignal1) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Error signal");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
void manejadorSignal1() {
    //Matar procesos hijos con kill(PID_HIJO,SEÑAL);
}
```